# How to find an element in XML using Xquery in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, find, xquery

In my XSLT using Xquery I need to find the Value for the given Key :

```
<ExtendedProperties>
    <ExtendedProperty>
        <Key>AvailabilityStatus</Key>
        <Value>test</Value>
    </ExtendedProperty>
    <ExtendedProperty>
        <Key>HomeDelivery</Key>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </ExtendedProperty>
    <ExtendedProperty>
        <Key>LogisticNature</Key>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </ExtendedProperty>
</ExtendedProperties>
```

Example : If I give the key AvailabilityStatus I should get the result : test

Comment: Can you give the xslt you've got so far so that we've got some context.

Comment: So in your output you want only a text token like test?

Comment: yes, just the result in the form of text which i want to compare with another values for example test == 'text'

Comment: Example using Xquery : /ExtendedProperties/ExtendedProperty[AvailabilityStatus]

Comment: Provide a sample of the required output if you want an answer. It's hard to say what you want starting from your description.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How does your XSLT use XQuery? Do you mean XPath?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I *think* you are trying to accomplish. I'm using XSLT 2.0 and passing the search string as a parameter to the stylesheet. If you need XSLT 1.0, we can easily modify the example.

Using your sample XML and passing 'AvailabilityStatus' as the `searchString` parameter, this XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="searchString"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="ExtendedProperties/ExtendedProperty[contains(lower-case(Key),lower-case($searchString))]/Value"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the wanted(??) output:

`test`

If you want a more exact match, use `=` instead of the `contains()` function and remove the `lower-case()` processing.

**EDIT**

After reading the comments for a third time, it seems like what you really want is the XPath. The XPath in my XSLT example probably isn't what you're looking for. Maybe something like this:

`/ExtendedProperties/ExtendedProperty[Key='AvailabilityStatus']/Value`